# Why UIView() background not apply? (programmatically)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to load `uiView`. And this view should have 50 points distance from right below label. But simulator shows more little distance.
So I tried to set background color of uiView to check how this view occupy, but it's not working? what is the main problem of my code?

here is screen shots and codes

```swift
private let helpLabelView: UIView = {
        let container = UIView()
        let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 20))
        label1.text = "비밀번호를 설정해주세요."
        label1.font = UIFont(name: "Pretendard-Regular", size: 15)
        label1.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 300, height: 20))
        label2.text = "(영어 대소문자, 숫자, 특수문자 각 1개 이상 사용)"
        label2.font = UIFont(name: "Pretendard-Regular", size: 15)
        label2.backgroundColor = .green
        
        container.addSubview(label1)
        container.addSubview(label2)
        
        container.backgroundColor = .brown // this line not applied
        
        return container
    }()
```

```swift
view.addSubview(helpLabelView)
helpLabelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

```swift
pwLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pwField.topAnchor, constant: -11),
            pwLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
            helpLabelView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pwLabel.topAnchor, constant: -50),
            helpLabelView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
```

*pwLabel is nearby below label of `HelpLabelView`*
*all views are set active*
[image]

Comment: The two labels' backgrounds completely covers up the entire brown background. What else did you expect to see? Also, what is `pwLabel` and `pwField`?

Comment: @Sweeper 
`pwField` is a textfield under the `pwLabel`, `pwLabel`is 비밀번호 label in screenshot. sorry for insufficient question.

Comment: @Sweeper
I've tried to set only uiview container's color, but it doesn't applied too

Comment: Actually you also forgot to constrain the size of `helpLabelView`. That’s probably why the spacing looks so small.

Comment: @Sweeper 
I solved problem from your comment thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is no constraints on the *size* of `helpLabelView`, so its size is automatically set to (0, 0). The container view is like a single invisible point at the top left of the blue label.

From the picture, the top left of the blue label is indeed about 50 points away from the top of `pwLabel`, considering the green and blue labels all have a height of 20.

So a simple solution is to just add some constraints regarding the width and height:

```
helpLabelView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
helpLabelView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
```

This would fix the spacing issue, but you will still not see the brown background, because the blue and green backgrounds completely covers up the background of `helpLabelView`. To see the brown background, you would need to give it a larger size.

Last but not least, consider using a `UIStackView` to contain the two labels, instead of hardcoding the widths and heights of everything.